# How detect a tap outside a widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a menu that is displayed when a button is pressed, I want to be able to close the menu when there is a Tap outside the menu, just like a regular `PopupMenuButton`.

My current solution is use a `Stack` that have a `GestureDetector` as one of its children to detect the taps but with this solution my alignment is controlled by the `Stack`, I just want the alignment to be controlled by the parent of the menu not the `Stack`.

```
//part of the build method

return Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(             
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                //Holds the list of menu items
                menuContainer, 
                //button that displays the menu
                floatingActionButton]                                 
              ),
              //Detects taps outside the menu
              GestureDetector(onTap: (() => setVisibility(false))
        )
      ]
    );
```

Comment: It is not possible to detect taps outside of a widget. You need to refractor your layout so that it's not outside anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior using a custom route:

```
class CustomDialog extends PopupRoute {
  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.transparent;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return _builder(context);
  }

  Widget _builder(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
  }

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 300);
}
```

The `barrierDismissible` override indicates if the route should be popped out of the stack when a touch is detected outside the widget. Whenever you want to show the menu you could call `Navigator.of(context).push(CustomDialog())`.

This solution does not allow the menu to return any value, if you need data back from it then you could override ModalRoute instead and achieve a similar result.

Comment: That works, is possible to recieve a callback when the Route is being dimissed? to make a animated transition before

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you override ModalRoute<T> instead of PopupRoute. Where T is the type of the value you are going to return. Afterwards, you can have something like Navigator.pop(context, result) inside the CustomDialog class, where result is what you're returning to the caller (aka where Navigator.push was called).

Answer (score 30):

There is straightforward way to do that in Flutter:

```dart
TapRegion(
  onTapInside: (tap) {
    print('On Tap Inside!!');
  },
  onTapOutside: (tap) {
    print('On Tap Outside!!');
  },
  child: ...,
)
```

Comment: Why isn't this the current solution? The question is "outside a widget" and not dialog! We should please differntiate between Routed stuff and raw Widgets!

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Mariano Uvalle's answer, thanks by the way,  no longer works because they put an assert in the _buildModalBarrier checking if you set the barrier color to transparent.

My work around was to copy the `/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart` file into my own `/libs` folder and comment out this assert at `line: 1226`

```dart
      assert(barrierColor != _kTransparent);
```

also replace these non-`dart:` or `package:` imports at the top

```dart
import 'basic.dart';
import 'focus_manager.dart';
import 'focus_scope.dart';
import 'framework.dart';
import 'modal_barrier.dart';
import 'navigator.dart';
import 'overlay.dart';
import 'page_storage.dart';
import 'transitions.dart';
```

with

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```

then in my app
`import 'routes.dart' as my;`
and use use Mariano Uvalle's `class` he posted. Only `extend` it is as `my.PopupRoute` instead.

It's not perfect but it will do the trick.

---

Edit: 
I've tried the ModalRoute version of the above and it also works:

```dart
class CustomDialog extends my.ModalRoute<bool> {

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.transparent;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return _builder(context);
  }


  Widget _builder(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Container(height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: Material(elevation: 8.0,
          child:
            Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),
                  title: new Text('Add Image'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  @override
  bool get maintainState => false;

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;
}
```

and I put this in a onpressed value:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
                          bool notDismissed = await Navigator.of(context).push(CustomDialog());
                          if (notDismissed == true)
                          {
                            print('user clicke option');
                          }
                          else {
                            print('dismissed dialog');
                          }
```

Again it's not perfect but it may come in handy at some point. I however found I really need to detect a clicks on specific widgets for my use case.

Comment: Can you pass a parameter to the CustomDialog?

Answer (score 3):

bobajeff's answer worked for me, but I found that using overriding the opaque getter and setting the barrierColor getter to null was a little cleaner.

```
class CustomDialog extends PageRoute {
  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return _builder(context);
  }

  Widget _builder(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 300);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a easy way i just did, Just put a GestureDetector inside another one, then set the onTap action if that's your case on both GestureDetector's, with the diference that in one you are gonna put an action, an in the other one you can just leave it empty, just like this.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { //The Gesture you dont want to afect the rest
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child:GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {}, //This way is not going to afect the inside widget
            child: Container() //your widget
            )
          )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Flutter's `TapRegion` itself: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion-class.html